# Linux OpenVPN systemctl list-units configuration

Tags: linux, openvpn

I have set up OpenVPN client on my Linux laptop (Debian based).

It works by manually starting things up. 
However, I had tried to do this previously with little success.

I checked my processes, to see what have spun up. I noticed 2 openvpn processes. I noticed the client process. That I expected. However, I did not expect an openvpn which appears to be starting the server mode of the service.

I look at systemctl to see what units were listed, active, etc.

```
systemctl list-units | grep openvpn
```

There were 5 units listed.

```
openvpn.service
openvpn@client.service
openvpn@<actual specific vpn>.service
openvpn@server.service
system-openvpn.slice
```

I recognize the `<actual specific vpn>` as that is the provider I am connecting to. However, I do not recognize the rest.

My first question is

1. Can I just disable/remove them all and enable/start the one I want?
2. What is the command(s) that I should use to do the above task?

Answer (score 1):

> Can i just disable/remove them all and enable/start the one I want.

Yes, you can. However, keep in mind that 2 of those are "meta" services that'd always work and 1 is a [slice](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html).

The services **openvpn.service**, **openvpn@.service** will always work and you shouldn't worry about them. And **system-openvpn.slice** is also something you shouldn't worry about, it's like a cgroup in which all openvpn services run.

As you've listed the services that are running, we can see that the important ones are two:

```
openvpn@client.service
openvpn@server.service
```

You can disable the server service with the following command:

```
systemctl disable openvpn@server.service
```

I suggest the rest be left alone. Read below if you want to know why the **openvpn@server.service** is starting like it is.

---

The client services is running as expected, but the most likely reason why the **openvpn@server.service** is the following systemd configuration for **openvpn@.service**:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-%i --status /run/openvpn/%i.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/%i.pid
```

This means that **openvpn** can start seperate services for seperate configuration files in your `/etc/openvpn/` directory. If **openvpn@server.service** is running, you most likely have a `/etc/openvpn/server.config`. Nonetheless, you can still disable it.

---

> what is the command(s) that I should use to do the above task.

The most common commands you can use are as follows:

**1.** Disabling/enabling a service:

```
systemctl disable/enable service_name.service
```

**2.** Starting/stopping/restarting a service:

```
systemctl start/stop/restart service_name.service
```

To read more: **[systemctl manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)**